# Best practice for different NGRX effects when they lead to same action but in some cases are triggered in a row

Tags: angular, ngrx

**Situation:**
Lets say we have to fetch 3 sets of data from different endpoints that all result in an extension of a set of answers in the store. each time we get a new addition of one of these 3 sources we want to save the now extended answers object to the store.

Effects very simplified like this:

- ofType(newRedAnswers) => map(saveAnswersToLocal)
- ofType(newBlueAnswers) => map(saveAnswersToLocal)
- ofType(newGreenAnswers) => map(saveAnswersToLocal)

Most of the times we get the source indepedantly from each other, when ever we need to update that specific group.

**Problem:** On start up we always get all three initially in a row. But I don't want to have 3 times of saving them.
I wonder whats the most elegant way to do it? Write new effects? Conditions? Seperate in different actions like "Load Red Answers On Startup" und "Load Red Answers During Runtime" ?

Would you even terrorize your backend guy until he makes you a unified route with all 3 only for startup purpose?

Thanks for any advice, guys!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
effect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(newRedAnswers, newBlueAnswers, newGreenAnswers),
  // I would research out of mergeMap, switchMap, or concatMap, which one to use
  // switchMap will cancel the previous request that hasn't loaded if a new request comes in
  switchMap(action => {
    const endObservable$;
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'Red':
        // assign http of red's endpoint to endObservable$
      case 'Blue':
        // assign http of blue's endpoint to endObservable$
      case 'Green':
       // assign http of green's endpoint to endObservable$
    }
    return endObservable.pipe(
      map(data => saveAnswersToLocal(data)),
      catchError(err => /*handle error */),
    )
  }),
);
```

As for best practice, I am not sure.

Comment: thanks for your approach. but as i can see it this would still lead to 3x triggering the saveAnswersToLocal. i thought there was some elegant way to chain them at startup and then only save once. (and still be able to only one of the data sources and save seperately)